# i want to check if Date is correct like (2021-02-31 is not correct)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to verify if date (java.util.Date) is correct
like 2021/02/31 does not exist

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
  try{
      dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date));
  } catch(ParseException e) {
     return false;
  }
  return true;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### java.time

I recommend you do it using `java.time`, the modern date-time API.<sup>*</sup>

Use [`DateTimeFormatter#withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withResolverStyle-java.time.format.ResolverStyle-) to resolve a date strictly. If the input is incorrect, [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) is thrown.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate = "2021/02/31";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM/dd", Locale.ENGLISH)
                .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
        try {
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(strDate, dtf);
            // ...
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Text '2021/02/31' could not be parsed: Invalid date 'FEBRUARY 31'
```

**[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/Cs9u15)**

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Also, note that `yyyy-mm-dd` is not a correct format for your date string which has `/` instead of `-` and `m` is used for a minute, not a month for which you have to use `M`.

---

<sup>* The `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

First of all your date format uses `mm` which represents minutes, for months it needs to be `MM`.

Secondly I am not sure what you meant to do with `dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date));`. The inner part (`dateFormat.format(Date)`) should be used to convert a date to a string, and the outer part (`dateFormat.parse(String)`) is to convert a string to a date. So this seems to be a bit of a pointless operation.

I think what you meant was something like this, which should check the validity of date properly:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
try{
    dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format("2021-02-31"));
} catch(ParseException e) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

---

Having said this, using the new Java Date-Time APIs is always a better approach, so I would defer to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66587855/642706) from @ArvindKumarAvinash for a more future-proof solution.